# Scheme ill-formed special form

Tags: scheme

I'm very new to Scheme and I'm getting an "ill-formed special form" error when I try to use this function. I want the function to return *left* if the length of *original* is 0. Else I want it to execute the calls to append and the recursive call. I imagine I've probably done something really silly that is causing this. ANy help?

```
(define (partition left right original)
(if (= (length original) 0) left
    (append left (car original))
        (append right (car (reverse original)))
              (partition left right (reverse original))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I begin, do try to [indent your programs properly](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style). In this case, it would have made the error much more obvious.

You're running into a speedbump that many Scheme newbies hit coming from other languages:

`if` in Lisp (including scheme) is actually the ternary operator, not the `if` block from the C-like world.

Your code tries to present `if` with more than three forms, so it fails. Naively, what you could do is use the block construct `begin` (`progn` in Common Lisp) to make sure that a single branch of the conditional only contains a single form.

```
(define (partition left right original)
  (if (= (length original) 0)
      left
      (begin 
        (append left (car original))
        (append right (car (reverse original)))
        (partition left right (reverse original)))))
```

Now, I get the feeling that this won't do what you want either, because `append` is functional (that is, it returns a result without modifying its arguments). In other words, neither of your calls to `append` will do anything, and `original` will never get shorter. What you actually seem to want here is something like

```
(define (partition left right original)
  (if (= (length original) 0)
      left
      (partition (cons (car original) left)
                 (cons (last original) right)
                 (cdr (take original (- (length original) 1))))))
```

Comment: By the way, you may want to investigate a Scheme implementation that gives good error messages.  In Racket, for example, it gives the following error message for your original code: "if: bad syntax (has 5 parts after keyword) in ..."

Comment: The link to "indent properly" is no longer available. Do you have any new link where we can refer ?

Answer (score 2):

An `if` form consists of 4 parts:

1. The word `if`.
2. The condition.
3. The then-branch.
4. The else-branch.

Your `if`-form however consists of 6 parts. `(= (length original) 0)` is the condition. `left` is the then-branch and `(append left (car original))` is the else-branch. But what are the other two supposed to be? To the reader it's obvious, that they're still supposed to be part of the else-branch, but the compiler can't know that. As far as the compiler knows you might just as well have intended for `left` and `(append left ...)` to go in the then-branch and for the other two to go in the `else` branch.

If you want to execute multiple expressions inside an `if`, you need some way to group together the expressions that belong in the same branch. You do that using `begin` like this:

```
(if condition
  (begin
    (do-something-in-the-then-branch)
    (do-something-else-in-the-then-branch))
  (begin
    (do-something-in-the-else-branch)
    (do-something-else-in-the-else-branch)))
```

However in your case this won't actually help because `append` doesn't work in-place. I.e. if you do `(append left (car original))`, the value of `left` won't actually be changed. Instead `append` will return a new list that contains the contents of `left` and `(car original)` without actually changing either of the lists. So to make use of `append`'s result, you'll need to use its return value.

So to make your function work, you should either pass the calls to append directly as arguments to `partition` or use `let` to assign the results to variables and pass the variables to `partition`.